# What types of materials can be tested in a split Hopkinson pressure bar?

Tags: materials, pressure

A split Hopkinson pressure bar can test different types of specimens, I would like to know what types of materials that are suitable to be tested with this method?

Comment: +1. Before anyone suggests to migrate to engineering, let's wait for a response to this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56607970#56607970. If someone here might know the answer, please go ahead!

Comment: +1 Are you asking for the geometrical form, the material should be so that it can be tested? If so usually you would take samples with circular cross-sections and in some cases, square cross-sections are preferred. Or is the question regarding some other physical parameter? It would be nice if you could expand a bit more on that :)

Comment: Thank you @AnoopANair, well I am asking in the form of ductile materials, brittle materials or so? or generally it can be applied to any kind of materials?

Comment: Search "instrumented Charpy Tests". Well established technology for dynamic test  response of impact loads ( primarily steels).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.hbm.com/en/2996/split-hopkinson-bar-material-tests/
"
How does it differ from a static material testing machine?

What is the difference between using a split Hopkinson bar and a static material testing machine?

Young's modulus is usually determined from a stress-strain-curve created in a testing machine under quasi-static conditions - i.e. with (very) small strain rates. However, material behavior may differ substantially with dynamic loads. Depending on whether dynamic loads, too, occur in a structure, the design engineer needs to know the material's dynamic properties as well.

Normally a simple material testing machine is not able to apply the required high strain rates."

as far i can tell its very useful for example if the incident bar is hit with a projectile to se how the material deforms under heavy stress, however i doubt a high energy impact is needed at at, but seems highly suitable for just that, so about anything, add some high speed cameras and it can probably be used to see what happens to about anything under stress.